# Passing Vector as a Reference to Std::Tuple and Modifying It

Tags: c++, c++14, std, pass-by-reference, stdvector

I am trying to use tuples inside a priority_queue and my tuples contain vectors. I want to be able to modify these vectors but when I delete items from a vector, it does not change the actual content. I think I am modifying the values instead of references but I am not very experienced with c++ and need some help with fixing this code:

I define my tuples like this:

```
   using tuple_type = std::tuple<std::vector<uint64_t>, File*, size_t>;
   auto comparator = [](tuple_type const &a, tuple_type const &b) {
      return std::get<0>(a).front()> std::get<0>(b).front();
   };

   std::priority_queue<tuple_type, std::vector<tuple_type>, decltype(comparator)> pq{comparator};
```

and I access them like this:

```
      auto elem = pq.top();
      auto *file = std::get<1>(elem);
      auto block_containing_smallest_element = std::get<0>(elem);
      to_write.push_back(block_containing_smallest_element.front());
      block_containing_smallest_element.erase(block_containing_smallest_element.begin());
```

I erase the first element but in the next iteration, it is still there. I tried writing to tuple using std::get<0>(elem) = block_containing_smallest_element but it also did not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Not directly related, but you're not allowed to modify elements in the `std::priority_queue`. 2) Rule of thumb: `auto` is never a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I am modifying the values instead of references

That is the correct diagnosis of the problem.

As has been pointed out in a comment, the other issue is that you cannnot modify modify elements in a `std::priority_queue` directly. You'll have to:

1. Get an element by value.
2. Modify the element.
3. Pop the element from the queue.
4. Push the element on to the queue.

Use

```
auto elem = pq.top();
auto *file = std::get<1>(elem);
auto& block_containing_smallest_element = std::get<0>(elem);
to_write.push_back(block_containing_smallest_element.front());
block_containing_smallest_element.erase(block_containing_smallest_element.begin());
pq.pop();
pq.push(elem);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have modified my code but now the line with .erase gives the following compile error: No matching member function for call to 'erase' candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::vector<unsigned long long>', but method is not marked const candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided. Could you also help me with that :)

Comment: This code, followed by `block_containing_smallest_element.erase()` should not compile. `std::priority_queue::top()` returns a const-reference.

Comment: @erinc, you can't modify elements in the `std::priority_queue`. Pop the element, modify it and then push it back.

Comment: Thank you @Evg. I am new with c++ and especially the modern features so I was struggling a bit. I will keep those in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is clear because the actual element is in the priority queue, not in the auto variable. If you see this line of your code :

```
auto block_containing_smallest_element = std::get<0>(elem);
```

Here, a new variable is made which is of type `auto`, so that c++ figures out the type on its own, but when you erase it in the last line,

```
block_containing_smallest_element.erase(block_containing_smallest_element.begin());
```

Here you are just erasing a variable from a variable !!, here you need to give this:

```
auto& elem = pq.top();
auto *file = std::get<1>(elem);
auto& block_containing_smallest_element = std::get<0>(elem);
```

Also remember that it is a **PIRORITY QUEUE**, so even though you remove an element from the variable it work affect the actual one because it is not pointing to the original PQ

Comment: I didn't get what this answer tries to convey. OP wants to erase an element not from a priority queue, but from an element of a priority queue.

Comment: With `auto&` this code won't compile if `erase()` is applied to `block_containing_smallest_element`, because `auto&` will be a const reference. See my comment below another answer.